# Migration path(s) for tests in QADirector

Tags: test-management, tools, export

We have a lot of tests in QADirector. The largest of our 26 projects has more than 1100 test scripts. Since QADirector is no longer supported, I'm looking for possible migration paths.

The only know migration path to me is to SilkCentral using the [SilkCentral 
TestManager Migration Utility (PDF)](http://www.microfocus.com/_ex/community/knowledgebase/TelligentArticleResources/1348_tmqadmigrationutility.pdf). However, we don't own a SilkCentral license (yet) and according to the feedback of the support, they have never migrated such a large database.

Are there other alternatives for converting the tests of QADirector into a format matching any other test tool?

*I'm aware the nature of this question could be flagged as "too broad". If your vote for "too broad", please proove your flag by mentioning at least one possible way in the comments - because I doubt there is more than one (if any) answer out there.*

Answer (score 1):

We operate Enterprise Tester. A test management tool that is used by global organsiations as a replacement for QA Director. We offer the ability to migrate all your data (requirements, tests, executions and bugs plus the relationships) across to Enterprise Tester.

You can check us out at [www.catchsoftware.com](http://www.catchsoftware.com) if you'd like to or drop me a line directly.
Regards
Bryce

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for HP Quality Center or [Zephyr](http://www.getzephyr.com/)

Also can try this tool http://www.qmetry.com/

Answer (score 0):

We Migrated from previous tool to [Meliora testlab](https://www.melioratestlab.com/). As suggested, the [HP ALM](http://www8.hp.com/fi/fi/software-solutions/application-lifecycle-management.html) has also possibility to migrate the test data. Both tools can easily handle your amount of test scripts. For both tools you can ask the manufacturer to migrate the data for you or import it yourself.

Comment: I contacted Meliora and the import seems to work for CSV data only. Unfortunately, there is no CSV export from QADirector.